# Firefox maximize doesn't trigger resize Event

Tags: jquery, firefox, resize

I try to catch resize events with jquery and the

```
$(window).resize(function() { }
```

Everything works fine, except when I use the maximize Button in Firefox, the event is not thrown.

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: `$(window).resize(function() { console.log('resized!'); });` works for me in Firefox 8 with jQuery 1.6.2. Which browser/jQuery are you using and could you post your complete code that is not working?

Comment: Works for me, at least with FF 5.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: You forgot the `)` at the end.

Comment: @andyb, Firefox 8 is not out yet, I think it is due for next week.

Comment: @Johnny5 Firefox 8 - nightly builds have been out for ages :-)

Comment: seems to work now... must have been the ) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
   console.log('resize!');
});
```

This works in FF5 / osx

Answer (score 25):

Seems not working because it takes a bit to maximize I think, this works for me:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log('resize');
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('resize me later');
  }, 150);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem with my project, and had to find out that the CSS transition was causing the issue.

So I changed the CSS transition from ALL to only the shadow (thus the change in the width of the div wasn't "animated" any more) and then maximizing the browser window, combined with window.resize() was working as expected!

Comment: Thank you! This explains my problem too.